# invalid stream header: 47455420 - Java Input Stream

Tags: header, stream, ioexception

**Hello World!**

Currently I'm writing a simple Client/Server application which uses sockets to do the communitcation. My Client and my Server application are working fine with each other but if I try to query my Server application with a real web-browser (like Mozilla Firefox), then it comes to an exception.

I think that my streams are not compatible with Mozilla Firefox. This little code line always leads to an IOException with the error message "invalid stream header: 47455420".

From Firefox I try to connect via: http://localhost:7777/some-webpage.html

This is my code:

```
server = new ServerSocket(7777);
Socket socket = server.accept();
try
{
    ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    System.out.println("This exception happens :-(");
    System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Does anybody know why this happens?
Help is seen with pleasure.

Greetings

Benny

Answer (score 2):

The ObjectInputStream expects a binary format. You can't use a web browser to produce the binary format that it reads. The web browser will talk HTTP protocol, and your server is not expecting that at all.

You probably need to learn about web services. You might find the JAX-RS support in [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org)  convenient for what you seem to want to do.

To just drop in to HTTP, the minimal thing to do is implement a servlet: google would be your friend in learning about them.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.Is there a library to easily import the HTTP protocol? Or can I achieve that with just changing my Input Stream format?

Comment: I use the standard InputStream now instead of ObjectInputStream. This fits perfectly for webbrowsers and can be read with an InputStreamReader in a BufferedReader. I've also implemented the HTTP/1.1 basics so it works now. :-) Thanks for your advice.